# Apache Spark: map vs mapPartitions?

Tags: performance, scala, apache-spark, rdd

What's the difference between an [RDD's](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD) `map` and `mapPartitions` method? And does `flatMap` behave like `map` or like `mapPartitions`? Thanks.

(edit)
i.e. what is the difference (either semantically or in terms of execution) between

```
  def map[A, B](rdd: RDD[A], fn: (A => B))
               (implicit a: Manifest[A], b: Manifest[B]): RDD[B] = {
    rdd.mapPartitions({ iter: Iterator[A] => for (i <- iter) yield fn(i) },
      preservesPartitioning = true)
  }
```

And:

```
  def map[A, B](rdd: RDD[A], fn: (A => B))
               (implicit a: Manifest[A], b: Manifest[B]): RDD[B] = {
    rdd.map(fn)
  }
```

Comment: After reading the below answer, you can have a look at [this experience] shared by someone who actually used it.(https://bzhangusc.wordpress.com/2014/06/19/optimize-map-performamce-with-mappartitions/)

https://bzhangusc.wordpress.com/2014/06/19/optimize-map-performamce-with-mappartitions/

Answer (score 132, accepted):

> What's the difference between an RDD's map and mapPartitions method?

The method [map](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html?highlight=rdd#pyspark.RDD.map) converts each *element* of the source RDD into a single element of the result RDD by applying a function. [mapPartitions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html?highlight=rdd#pyspark.RDD.mapPartitions) converts each *partition* of the source RDD into multiple elements of the result (possibly none).

> And does flatMap behave like map or like mapPartitions?

Neither, [flatMap](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html?highlight=rdd#pyspark.RDD.flatMap) works on a single element (as `map`) and produces multiple elements of the result (as `mapPartitions`).

Comment: Thanks - so does map cause shuffles (or otherwise change the number of partitions)? Does it move data between nodes? I've been using mapPartitions to avoid moving data between nodes, but wasn't sure if flapMap would do so.

Comment: If you look at the source -- https://github.com/apache/incubator-spark/blob/97ac06018206b593600594605be241d0cd706e08/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/MappedRDD.scala and https://github.com/apache/incubator-spark/blob/97ac06018206b593600594605be241d0cd706e08/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/FlatMappedRDD.scala -- both `map` and `flatMap` have exactly the same partitions as the parent.

Comment: As a note, a presentation provided by a speaker at the 2013 San Francisco Spark Summit (goo.gl/JZXDCR) highlights that tasks with high per-record overhead perform better with a mapPartition than with a map transformation. This is, according to the presentation, due to the high cost of setting up a new task.

Comment: That is indeed the case, if you can indeed do setup a single time for the entire partition. The example they give is the need to open a DB connection for instance (no need to do it on every record)

Comment: That said, not sure if there is a difference in parallel execution and memory usage between map and mapPartitions. For instance, map could work in parallel implicitly, mapPartitions forces you to iterate. Thus computation could be faster with map but if your execution on a single tuple uses a lot of temporary memory, mapPartitions could avoid GC and memory issues. No idea if this is the way it actually works, but my anecdotal evidence seems to imply this. Would love to have confirmation.

Comment: I'm seeing the opposite -- even with very small operations, its faster to call mapPartitions and iterate than call map.  I am assuming that this is just the overhead of starting the language engine that will process the map task.  (I'm in R, which may have more startup overhead.)  If you would be performing multiple operations, then mapPartitions seems to be quite a bit faster -- I'm assuming this is because it reads the RDD only once.  Even if the RDD is cached in RAM, that saves a lot of overhead from type conversion.

Comment: `map` basically takes your function `f`, and passes it into `iter.map(f)`. So basically its a convenience method that wraps `mapPartitions`. I'd be surprised if there was a performance advantage either way for a pure map style transformation job (i.e. where the function is identical), if you need to create some objects for processing, if these objects can be shared then `mapPartitions` would be advantageous.

Comment: Using mapPartitions seems to make sense performance wise, if you have a reduce operation, that can be split up in a (1) 'reduce per partition' operation and a (2) 'reduce partition results' operation. The mapPartition can return an Iterable with 'number of partitions' elements, that can then be reduced to the final result.

Answer (score 175):

## Imp. TIP :

> Whenever you have heavyweight initialization that should be done once
>   for many `RDD` elements rather than once per `RDD` element, and if this
>   initialization, such as creation of objects from a third-party
>   library, cannot be serialized (so that Spark can transmit it across
>   the cluster to the worker nodes), use `mapPartitions()` instead of
>   `map()`. `mapPartitions()` provides for the initialization to be done
>   once per worker task/thread/partition instead of once per `RDD` data
>   element for [***example :***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37915154/647053) see below.

```
val newRd = myRdd.mapPartitions(partition => {
  val connection = new DbConnection /*creates a db connection per partition*/

  val newPartition = partition.map(record => {
    readMatchingFromDB(record, connection)
  }).toList // consumes the iterator, thus calls readMatchingFromDB 

  connection.close() // close dbconnection here
  newPartition.iterator // create a new iterator
})
```

---

> Q2. ***does `flatMap` behave like map or like `mapPartitions`?***

Yes. please see example 2 of `flatmap`.. its self explanatory.

> Q1. ***What's the difference between an RDD's `map` and `mapPartitions`***
>
> `map` works the function being utilized at a per element level while
>   `mapPartitions` exercises the function at the partition level.

***Example Scenario* :**  if we have 100K elements in a particular `RDD` partition then we will fire off the function being used by the mapping transformation 100K times when we use `map`.

Conversely, if we use `mapPartitions` then we will only call the particular function one time, but we will pass in all 100K records and get back all responses in one function call.

*There will be performance gain since `map` works on a particular function so many times, especially if the function is doing something expensive each time that it wouldn't need to do if we passed in all the elements at once(in case of `mappartitions`).*

## map

> Applies a transformation function on each item of the RDD and returns
>   the result as a new RDD.
>
> **Listing Variants**
>
> def map[U: ClassTag](f: T => U): RDD[U]

Example :

```
val a = sc.parallelize(List("dog", "salmon", "salmon", "rat", "elephant"), 3)
 val b = a.map(_.length)
 val c = a.zip(b)
 c.collect
 res0: Array[(String, Int)] = Array((dog,3), (salmon,6), (salmon,6), (rat,3), (elephant,8))
```

## mapPartitions

> This is a specialized map that is called only once for each partition.
>   The entire content of the respective partitions is available as a
>   sequential stream of values via the input argument (Iterarator[T]).
>   The custom function must return yet another Iterator[U]. The combined
>   result iterators are automatically converted into a new RDD. Please
>   note, that the tuples (3,4) and (6,7) are missing from the following
>   result due to the partitioning we chose.
>
> `preservesPartitioning` indicates whether the input function preserves the 
>   partitioner, which should be `false` unless this is a pair RDD and the input 
>   function doesn't modify the keys.
>
> ***Listing Variants***
>
> def mapPartitions[U: ClassTag](f: Iterator[T] => Iterator[U],
>   preservesPartitioning: Boolean = false): RDD[U]

Example 1

```
val a = sc.parallelize(1 to 9, 3)
 def myfunc[T](iter: Iterator[T]) : Iterator[(T, T)] = {
   var res = List[(T, T)]()
   var pre = iter.next
   while (iter.hasNext)
   {
     val cur = iter.next;
     res .::= (pre, cur)
     pre = cur;
   }
   res.iterator
 }
 a.mapPartitions(myfunc).collect
 res0: Array[(Int, Int)] = Array((2,3), (1,2), (5,6), (4,5), (8,9), (7,8))
```

Example 2

```
val x = sc.parallelize(List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,10), 3)
 def myfunc(iter: Iterator[Int]) : Iterator[Int] = {
   var res = List[Int]()
   while (iter.hasNext) {
     val cur = iter.next;
     res = res ::: List.fill(scala.util.Random.nextInt(10))(cur)
   }
   res.iterator
 }
 x.mapPartitions(myfunc).collect
 // some of the number are not outputted at all. This is because the random number generated for it is zero.
 res8: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 7, 7, 7, 9, 9, 10)
```

The above program can also be written using flatMap as follows.

Example 2 using flatmap

```
val x  = sc.parallelize(1 to 10, 3)
 x.flatMap(List.fill(scala.util.Random.nextInt(10))(_)).collect

 res1: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10)
```

## Conclusion :

`mapPartitions` transformation is faster than `map` since it calls your function once/partition, not once/element..

Further reading : [foreach Vs foreachPartitions When to use What?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30484701/apache-spark-foreach-vs-foreachpartitions-when-to-use-what)

Comment: I know that you can use `map` or `mapPartitions` to achieve the same result (see the two examples in the question); this question is about why you'd choose one way over the other. The comments in the other answer are really useful! Also, you didn't mention that `map` and `flatMap` pass `false` to `preservesPartitioning`, and what the implications of that are.

Comment: the function executed everytime versus function execute once for the parition was the link I was missing. Having access to more than one data record at a time with mapPartition is an invaluable thing. appreciate the answer

Comment: Is there a scenario where `map` is better than `mapPartitions`? If `mapPartitions` is so good, why isn't it the default map implementation?

Comment: @oneleggedmule: both are for different requirements we have to use wisely if you are instantiating resources like db connections (like shown in the above example) which are costly then mappartitions is right approach since one connection per partition. also saveAsTextFile internally used mappartitions  [see](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.scala)

Comment: @oneleggedmule From my point of view, map() is easier to understand and learn, and it is also a common method of many different languages. It may be easier to use as well than mapPartitions() if someone is not familiar with this Spark specific method at the beginning. If there is no performance difference then I prefer to use map().

Comment: So if the results are not entirely correct, then the use of mapPartitions is less handy. That said the number of errors is low and it is trade off. I am wondering why the architecture is not standardly mapPartitions based.

Comment: @RamGhadiyaram Can you explain more detailed about  "why tuples (3,4) and (6,7) are missing?"

Answer (score 15):

**Map** :

> 1. It processes one row at a  time ,  very similar to map() method of MapReduce.
> 2. You return from the transformation after every row.

**MapPartitions**

> 1. It processes the complete partition in one go.
> 2. You can return from the function only once after processing the whole partition.
> 3. All intermediate results needs to be held in memory till you process the whole partition.
> 4. Provides you like  setup() map() and cleanup() function of MapReduce
>
> `Map Vs mapPartitions` 
>   http://bytepadding.com/big-data/spark/spark-map-vs-mappartitions/
>
> `Spark Map`  http://bytepadding.com/big-data/spark/spark-map/
>
> `Spark mapPartitions`
>   http://bytepadding.com/big-data/spark/spark-mappartitions/

Comment: regarding 2 - if you're performing iterator-to-iterator transformations, and not materializing the iterator to a collection of some sort, you won't have to hold the entire partition in memory, in fact, that way spark will be able to spill parts of the partition to disk.

Comment: You dont have to hold the entire partition in memory, but the result.  You cannot return the result until you have processed the whole partition

Answer (score 0):

**Map:**

Map transformation.

The map works on a single Row at a time.

Map returns after each input Row.

The map doesn’t hold the output result in Memory.

Map no way to figure out then to end the service.

```
// map example

val dfList = (1 to 100) toList

val df = dfList.toDF()

val dfInt = df.map(x => x.getInt(0)+2)

display(dfInt)
```

**MapPartition:**

MapPartition transformation.

MapPartition works on a partition at a time.

MapPartition returns after processing all the rows in the partition.

MapPartition output is retained in memory, as it can return after processing all the rows in a particular partition.

MapPartition service can be shut down before returning.

```
// MapPartition example

Val dfList = (1 to 100) toList

Val df = dfList.toDF()

Val df1 = df.repartition(4).rdd.mapPartition((int) => Iterator(itr.length))

Df1.collec()

//display(df1.collect())
```

For more details, please refer to the [Spark map vs mapPartitions transformation](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-map-vs-mappartitions-transformation/) article.

Hope this is helpful!