# When to use map vs mapPartitions in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I know the difference between `map` and `mapPartitions` which target elements and iterators of elements respectively.

When should I use which? If the overhead is similar, why would I ever use `mapPartitions`, since `map` is easier to write?

Answer (score 2):

`RDD.map` maps a function to each element of an RDD, whereas `RDD.mapPartitions` maps a function to each partition of an RDD.

`map` will not change the number of elements in an RDD, while `mapPartitions` might very well do so.

See also [this answer and comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21185092/apache-spark-map-vs-mappartitions) on a similar question.

Comment: Nice answer. Why it can change the number?

Comment: @gsamaras Because you might e.g. choose to create a new object for each partition which would then make up your new RDD. Your new RDD would then have as many elements as the former had partitions.