# Connect to Hbase using hadoop config in spark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hbase, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to create hbase connection in MapPartitionFunction of spark.

```
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
```

I tried the following code

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf()
            .setAppName("EnterPrise Risk Score")
            .setMaster("local");
    conf.set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer");
    conf.set("spark.kryo.registrationRequired", "true");
    conf.registerKryoClasses(new Class<?>[] {
                            Class.forName("org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration"),
                            Class.forName("org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Table"),
                            Class.forName("com.databricks.spark.avro.DefaultSource$SerializableConfiguration")});
    SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().config(conf)
            .getOrCreate();
Configuration hbaseConf= HBaseConfiguration
            .create(hadoopConf);
```

I am using sparkSession to create dataset and pass hbaseConf to create connections to hbase.

Is there any way to connect to hbase?

Comment: It seems that the class `org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration` is not serializable, yet you are trying to register it in `KryoSerializer `.

Comment: can you elaborate the question ? Have you tried `sparkonhbase`?

Comment: see this [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

You probably implicitly pass an HBase configuration to a spark action like this:

```java
Configuration hbaseConfiguration = HBaseConfiguration.create();
sc.hadoopFile(inDirTrails, AvroInputFormat.class, AvroWrapper.class, NullWritable.class)).mapPartitions( i -> {
    Connection connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(hbaseConfiguration)
    //more valid code
});
```

Why don't you just create Configuration right inside of it like this:

```java
sc.hadoopFile(inDirTrails, AvroInputFormat.class, AvroWrapper.class, NullWritable.class)).mapPartitions( i -> {
    Configuration hbaseConfiguration = HBaseConfiguration.create();
    hbaseConfiguration.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", HBASE_ZOOKEEPER_QUORUM);
    Connection connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(hbaseConfiguration)
    //more valid code
});
```

Comment: [mapPartitions method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21185092/apache-spark-map-vs-mappartitions) is good for creating connections or objects