# Solving task not serializable error in spark/scala while using stanford-nlp for name extraction

Tags: scala, apache-spark, serialization, stanford-nlp

I am trying to extract names from texts using stanford ner package in Spark/Scala. I have added the following in built.sbt:

```
libraryDependencies++=Seq(
"edu.stanford.nlp" % "stanford-corenlp" % "3.6.0",
"org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.0-M9"
)
```

Further, I have created an RDD where every element is a text(set of strings). Then, I have defined a function called "ner" which takes the text as input and returns names from them. For implemeting name extraction, here is the relevant part of code:

```
val serializedclassifier = "/home/hadoopuser/stanfordner/stanford-ner-2016-10-31/classifiers/german.conll.hgc_175m_600.crf.ser.gz"
val classifier = CRFClassifier.getClassifierNoExceptions(serializedclassifier)
def ner (a: String):String={
  val out = classifier.classify(a._2)
   ...
   ...
   ...}
```

The code gives me names when I do

```
rdd.take(10).foreach(x=>println(ner(x)))
```

but when I did

```
val rdd2 = rdd.map(x=>ner(x))
```

It threw the following error:

```
Loading classifier from /home/hadoopuser/stanfordner/stanford-ner-2016-10-31/classifiers/german.conll.hgc_175m_600.crf.ser.gz ... done [0.8 sec].
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:298)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2039)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$map$1.apply(RDD.scala:366)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$map$1.apply(RDD.scala:365)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:358)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.map(RDD.scala:365)
    at org.inno.redistagger.redistagger$.main(correcttags.scala:220)
    at org.inno.redistagger.redistagger.main(correcttags.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:736)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:185)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:210)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier, value: edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier@56dd6efa)
    - field (class: org.inno.redistagger.redistagger$$anonfun$9, name: classifier$1, type: class edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier)
    - object (class org.inno.redistagger.redistagger$$anonfun$9, <function1>)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:40)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:295)
    ... 20 more
```

To get rid of this error, I defined the classifier variable inside the "ner" function as this:

```
val serializedclassifier = "/home/hadoopuser/stanfordner/stanford-ner-2016-10-31/classifiers/german.conll.hgc_175m_600.crf.ser.gz"
def ner (a: String):String={
   val classifier = CRFClassifier.getClassifierNoExceptions(serializedclassifier)
  val out = classifier.classify(a._2)
   ...
   ...
   ...}
```

This solves the above error but a new problem has popped up. The above "ner" function creates a variable classifier for every element of the rdd which has around 5 million elements. Creating the variable which is basically connecting to the ner library takes 0.5 seconds and hence it would take a lot of time for the code to complete. How can I solve this or serialize the classifier without defining it within the "ner" function?

Comment: have you tried CRFClassifier as an object or CRFClassifier extends serializable

Comment: I mean `CRFClassifier.getClassifierNoExceptions(serializedclassifier)` should be in closure i.e within ner function or you need to serialize  CRFClassifier and put it out side the closure. other wise task not serializable exception will come

Comment: if you want to put classifier in side closure then use mappartitions rather than rdd.map check [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39203798/647053) so that classifier will be initialized once per partitions rather than once per element

Comment: that is my question. how do i serialize CRFClassifier outside the function?

Comment: you need to serialize CRFClassifier and put it out side the closure if you want that way

Comment: How to serialize the classifier outside the closure??

Comment: classifier  is class or object ?

Comment: if classifier is class  then serialize it .. is what I mean

Comment: val classifier = CRFClassifier.getClassifierNoExceptions(serializedclassifier)
should be object

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135071/discussion-between-ram-ghadiyaram-and-ravi-ranjan).

Comment: scala functions declared inside objects are equivalent to static Java methods. In order to call a static method, you don’t need to serialize the class, you need the declaring class to be reachable by the classloader (and it is the case, as the jar archives can be shared among driver and workers).

Comment: can you share the code snippet of CRFClassifier? as I believe there is something else

Comment: maybe sort of `new SparkContext(sparkConf)` inside your `CRFClassifier`