# how to return an Iterator when using mapPartitionsToPair / PairFlatMapFunction

Tags: java, apache-spark

when using mapPartitionsToPair / PairFlatMapFunction in spark, i found an example on Internet like

```
spark.read ().textFile (hdfsPath).javaRDD ()
.mapPartitionsToPair (new PairFlatMapFunction <Iterator <String>, String, String> () {
  public Iterable <Tuple2 <String, String> > call (Iterator <String> input) {
    List <String> result = new ArrayList <String> ();
    while (input.hasNext ()) result.add (doSomeThing (input.next ()));
    return result;
  }
});
```

but get error when complie

```
return type Iterable<Tuple2<String,String>> is not compatible with Iterator<Tuple2<String,String>>
```

I found the declaring of `call`

```
java.util.Iterator<scala.Tuple2<K,V>> call(T t)
```

so the call should be return an Iterator.

hence could someone help me how to return an Iterator on spark in javaRDD api?  thanks a lot

PS:
i tried the code like below doesnt work on the clusters:

```
public Iterator <Tuple2 <String, Strng> > call (Iterator <String> input) {
  List <String> result = new ArrayList <String> ();
  while (input.hasNext ()) result.add (doSomeThing (input.next ()));
  return result.iterator;
}
```

Comment: what is the use of mapPartitionsToPair? when should we use mapPartitionsToPair?

Answer (score 4):

Looks like spark version mismatch between your development environment and the cluster.

From Spark-2.0.0, Java RDD’s flatMap and mapPartitions functions return Java iterator and not iterable.

So, if your cluster has lesser than Spark-2.0.0 then, use the same spark version when developing also.

**For Spark-2.0.0 or greater**,

```
public Iterator <Tuple2 <String, Strng> > call (Iterator <String> input) {
List <String> result = new ArrayList <String> ();
while (input.hasNext ()) result.add (doSomeThing (input.next ()));
return result.iterator;
}
```

should work.

**For spark version less than 2.0.0**,

```
public Iterable <Tuple2 <String, String> > call (Iterator <String> input) {
List <String> result = new ArrayList <String> ();
while (input.hasNext ()) result.add (doSomeThing (input.next ()));
return result;
}
```

should work.

Comment: what is the use of mapPartitionsToPair? when should we use mapPartitionsToPair?

Comment: Whenever you want to convert the individual elements of a partition into pair(Tuple2<K, V>)

Comment: this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21185092/apache-spark-map-vs-mappartitions) is what I was asking for.. thnkyou