# What's the difference between element and partition in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark

I tried googling, but couldn't find an answer.

Taken from [Apache Spark: map vs mapPartitions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21185092/apache-spark-map-vs-mappartitions)

> What's the difference between an RDD's map and mapPartitions
>
> map works the function being utilized at a per **element level** while
>   mapPartitions exercises the function at the **partition level**.

In this context, what is element level? Is it just an individual row?

Comment: have you read [examples given by me there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39203798/647053) if you execute them you will understand in a practical way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apache Spark: map vs mapPartitions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21185092/apache-spark-map-vs-mappartitions)

Comment: @RamGhadiyaram yes, I read it and it created confusion for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In layman's terms you have a shelf with 10 racks and you have 100 balls like shown in picture. You will adjust 10 balls in 1 rack like wise.. 100 balls in 10 racks. is `balldata.repartition(10)`... thus uniformly distributed data(rather putting all 100 in one or 2 rack )

*Now instead of applying any logic on each ball (**element** or **row**), you are going to apply logic on **each rack (partition)** once. is the difference.*

In this case element is ball (a single row) and Partition is rack.

#### Advantage would be, if you are doing heavy initialization like opening database connections etc... for your processing logic... you will open one connection per partition (Rack :-)) to apply your logic rather than opening database connection for each element  (Ball :-))

I advise you to go through the [examples given there to understand better](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39203798/647053)

[image]

courtesy/credits for image [here](https://www.greatgolfmemories.com/100lobadiraw.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am confused because the result of map function I am trying to perform returns a list of tuples. So if do ```rdd = sc.parallelize(data)``` then ```res = rdd.map(self._prepricing)``` and my ```result.collect()``` is ```[(0,1,2),(3,4,5),(6,7,8)]```. Will element be a tuple or each number?

Comment: in this case a tuple

Comment: I see. Perhaps another question but in your conclusion ```mapPartitions transformation is faster than map since it calls your function once/partition, not once/element.```. What is the point of regular map if you can apply to many elements at once?