# SparkSQL join data with Rest API data

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need to join a hive table with JSON data from a Rest endpoint. Is it better to use a UDF or a data source (like temp table)? If using a UDF, what'd be a good way to throttle RPS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want need to look up the data in the Rest endpoint and spark you likely want to look at `mapParitions`.  Here's a [good explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21185092/apache-spark-map-vs-mappartitions) of why it could be better to use that just using map (and a UDF).   It would also speaks to throttling by implication.  Each partition = 1 executor.  So you can set a theoretical max using this. (I say theoretical max as you aren't always guaranteed to get all the executors you wish for.)