# Apache Spark mapPartitions vs UDF

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

May Apache Spark `mapPartitions` be considered like much performant substitution of Spark UDF with pretty much the same functionality?

Comment: UDF is more comparable to `map` rather than `mapPartition`. Please look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21185092/apache-spark-map-vs-mappartitions?rq=1

Comment: `Comparable` - yes, but I ask for the `consideration` while selecting the implementation. In other words - is it a good idea to use `mapPartitions` instead of `UDF` from application performance point of view?